# How to set Column as a variable

Tags: excel, vba

is it possible to set a column as an variable ? like setcolumn = B ? Because I had a vba code which help me create conditional formatting, however, everday i would need to change the column but the range stays the same. Based on my code below, i would need to change I2:I146 to J2:J146 and so on... everyday... Thus, i would like to know if its possible to set the column to a variable.

CURRENT CODE

```
Sub Button6_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Set ws = Sheets("COMPARISON")
i = 1

With Range("I2:I146").FormatConditions.Add( _
    Type:=xlExpression, _
    Formula1:="=((($I2-$E2)/$E2)*100) > 20")
    .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

End With

With Range("I2:I146").FormatConditions.Add( _
    Type:=xlCellValue, _
    Operator:=xlEqual, _
    Formula1:="0")
    .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End With

With Range("I2:I146").FormatConditions.Add( _
    Type:=xlExpression, _
    Formula1:="=AND($I2<$E2, $I2<>0)")
    .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
End With

Do Until i = 300
   If ws.Range("I" & i).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
       msg = "I" & i & " -" & " Data has INCREASED"
       MsgBox msg
   ElseIf ws.Range("I" & i).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
       msg1 = "I" & i & " -" & " Data is ZERO"
       MsgBox msg1
   ElseIf ws.Range("I" & i).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)       Then
   msg2 = "I" & i & " -" & " Data is DECREASED"
   MsgBox msg2
End If
i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we start with a String and then make a Range:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim bee As String, kolumn As Range

    bee = "B"
    Set kolumn = Range(bee & "1").EntireColumn
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the advice of John Coleman, I converted the formulas to `R1C1` notation.  Using `.Columns(ColNum).Rows("2:146")` allows us to set a variable for the column and keep the rows fixed.

Your message boxes made no sense to me.  You're formatting rows `2:146` but checking the formats in rows `1:300`. I guess maybe you are working with 2 different worksheets?  In any case, who wants to click 300 message boxes?  I modified that also.

[image]

### Code

```
Sub Button6_Click()
    Dim ColNum As Long
    'Assuming there is a header row and you want to format the last Column
    'ColNum = Sheets("COMPARISON").Cells(1, 5).End(xlToRight).Column

    ColNum = Sheets("COMPARISON").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    AddFormatConditions ColNum
    CreateMessage ColNum
End Sub

Sub AddFormatConditions(ColNum As Long)
    With Sheets("COMPARISON").Columns(ColNum).Rows("2:146")
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        With .FormatConditions.Add( _
             Type:=xlExpression, _
             Formula1:="=(((RC-RC5)/RC5)*100) > 20")
            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End With

        With .FormatConditions.Add( _
             Type:=xlCellValue, _
             Operator:=xlEqual, _
             Formula1:="0")
            .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            .Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        End With

        With .FormatConditions.Add( _
             Type:=xlExpression, _
             Formula1:="=AND(RC<RC5, RC<>0)")
            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Sub CreateMessage(ColNum As Long)
    Dim msg As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim clip As Object
    Dim change As Double
    Set clip = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    With Sheets("COMPARISON")

        For i = 2 To 300
            change = .Cells(i, ColNum) - .Cells(i, "E")

            If change > 0 Then
                msg = msg & .Cells(i).Address(False, False) & " -  Data has INCREASED By " & change & vbCrLf
            ElseIf change = 0 Then
                msg = msg & .Cells(i).Address(False, False) & " - Data is ZERO" & vbCrLf
            ElseIf change < 0 Then
                msg = msg & .Cells(i).Address(False, False) & " - Data is DECREASED By " & change & vbCrLf
            End If
        Next
    End With
    clip.SetText msg
    clip.PutInClipBoard
    Shell "NOTEPAD.EXE", vbNormalFocus
    SendKeys "^v"
    SendKeys "^{Home}"
End Sub
```

Comment: So how does the code compare the latest data with the base data ?

Comment: @Joel In your post `$E2` has a constant column reference.  Do you need it to compare the previous column?

Comment: Yes $E2 is the column with the original data, so the column with the latest data will have the compare it data with $E2. Hence thats why $E2 has a constant column reference

Comment: The condition formulas compare the current row-column ( `RC` ) with the current row-column E ( `RC5` )

Answer (score 0):

A column is a range, so you can set a range variable equal to it.

The following snippet might show you how it could be useful in your situation:

```
Sub test()
    Dim Col As Range
    Set Col = Range("B:B")
    Range(Col(2), Col(146)).Value = 1
End Sub
```

The code successfully sets all cells in `B2:B146` equal to 1.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but err its not just the range i need to change like  I2:I146 to J2:J146, but i would also need to change the formula in the codes as well. Such as "=((($I2-$E2)/$E2)*100) > 20") to "=((($J2-$E2)/$E2)*100) > 20").

Comment: @Joel You are switching the question now. You can of course assign strings such as "B" or "J" to string variables, and those string values can be used to construct other strings to be fed into `Range()` or `Formula()`. Just use the concatenation operator `&`.

Comment: Another idea - if you use `.FormulaR1C1` rather than `.Formula` then the references should update automatically. In any event, the answer of @GarysStudent illustrates how to use a string variable with the column letter.

Comment: Ah.. sorry I didn't specify my questions much better, but i really appreciate your help. Thanks.